# Highcharts.js: Group some series but not others in bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I would like to generate a bar chart with two series per "entry"

One will be a grouped bar consisting of multiple series, the other a single series.

I am basically trying to show multiple mailbox quota settings on one bar and the size of a users mailbox on another bar.

I've almost got this working as shown here using the Stacking option: http://jsfiddle.net/86WYS/

```
plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false,
                                formatter: function() {
                                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0,'.',',') + 'MB';
                                        }
                            },
                            shadow: false,
                            stacking: 'normal'
                        }
                    }
```

However, I don't want to stack the bar, I want to group them so the values don't add together but overlay each other instead.  The first bar should look like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/634t7/1/

```
plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false,
                                formatter: function() {
                                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0,'.',',') + 'MB';
                                        }
                            },
                            shadow: false,
                            grouping: false
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Best I can come up with is to turn both group and stack off, then manually set the position of your current size series:

```
bar: {
   dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
      formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0,'.',',') + 'MB';
      }
   },
   shadow: false,
   grouping: false,
   pointStart: -0.25  // set the point start back a bit, so category labels center
}
```

...

```
series: [{
    name: 'Current Size (MB)',
    color: colors[0],                       
    data: [
        {y: 2405.29, x: 0.25}, // manually set this column away from others
        {y: 2007.60, x: 1.25},
        {y: 1585.74, x: 2.25},
        {y: 711.07, x: 3.25}
    ]                        
},
```

...

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/86WYS/1/).